# turning Strings into Text in Haskell

Tags: haskell, d3.js, io

Using the Haskell d3.js library I am trying to make a bar chart a bar chart.

```
 import Control.Monad
 import qualified Data.Text as T
 import D3JS

 test :: Int -> IO ()
 test n = T.writeFile "generated.js" $ reify (box "#div1" (300,300) >>= bars n 300 (Data1D [100,20,80,60,120]))
```

Even with this simple example I have a number of questions.

- [**`import qualified`**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Import) seems to require namespaces.  Then instead of `Data.Text.writeFile` we can write `T.writeFile`
- `Data.Text.writeFile` does not appear listed in [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.2.0/docs/Data-Text.html)'s entry on `Data.Text` but I did find it in relation to [prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:writeFile).

Here is an example of a simple `T.writeFile` error:

```
> import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
> T.writeFile "helloWorld.txt" "Hello World!"

Couldn't match expected type ‘Text’ with actual type ‘String’
```

Hopefully all of this type-casting can be sorted out.  Then I have big question about how `reify` works.  For now... how do I even changed the String to a Text here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Data.Text.pack` to convert a `String` into `Text`:

```
pack :: String -> Text
```

Also, the Text version of `writeFile` appears in `Data.Text.IO`, e.g.:

```
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

T.writeFile "helloWorld.txt" (T.pack "Hello World!")
```

It's ok to import both `Data.Text` and `Data.Text.IO` as `T`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the conversion functions mentioned, you might want to use the `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` pragma at the top of your file to enable tho `OverloadedStrings` extension, which lets you write string literals, but automatically converting them to a compatible type (say `Text`).

Read more at https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-17-overloaded-strings.html.